# SNMP Trap on Unix

Tags: snmp

Nearly for 6 days I'm trying to get over this problem .

I have 2 machines . One of them is manager 10.201 machine, and the other is agent (10.226)

I've configured **manager's snmptrap.conf** file like this .

```
authCommunity  execute  public      default  .1
traphandle  default /usr/bin/traptoemail -s localhost -f snmp@localhost root@localhost
```

and then I've configured agent's `snmpd.conf` file like this.

```
###########################################################################
# SECTION: Access Control Setup

rocommunity  public  
rwcommunity  private



###########################################################################
# SECTION: System Information Setup

syslocation  "Izmir, 226. machine "
syscontact  info@abc.com

###########################################################################
# SECTION: Trap Destinations

trap2sink  10.0.0.201  162

authuser   read -s v2c guest_user noauth  .1
authuser   read -s usm guest_user noauth  .1
authcommunity read  public  default .1
iquerySecName guest_user
agentSecName  guest_user

monitor   -u guest_user  -r  1  "interface down" -o ifDescr ifOperStatus != 1
```

But I want to trap for agent machine's CPUIdle rate. For example I can get CpuIdle like this way by snmpwalk command.

```
# snmpwalk -v 2c  -c public 10.0.0.226 .iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.ucdavis.systemStats.**ssCpuIdle**.0
```

I want to trap to manager host(10.0.0.201) when agent's (10.0.0.226) CPuIdle rate is over 98.

Is there anyone that can help me ? Where I've done mistakes `.conf` files or anywhere else ?

Answer (score 2):

After reading `man snmpd.conf`, it seems that net-snmp can not send traps about CPuIdle rate.

A simple solution would be to have cron invoke a bash script that will check the top output for CPU idle % and send trap via `snmptrap` if it exceeds your threshold.